# Difference between "in" and "into"

Tags: differences, prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should “into” be used rather than “in to,” and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa)

I often get confused about which one to use: *in* or *into*? Kindly tell me what the difference is between the two.

Comment: Related to various degrees: [“Put it into the refrigerator” or “Put it in the refrigerator”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5653/), [Classify into 4 categories or in 4 categories](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5519/), [When should “into” be used rather than “in to”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/125/), [Difference between “into” and “onto”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/10191/), and a few others plus [this answer of nohat's](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2439//2441#2441) to a question that seems totally unrelated at first.