# Difference between "in to" and "into"

Tags: prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should “into” be used rather than “in to,” and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa)
>   [Difference between “in” and “into”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/difference-between-in-and-into)

I had to write a business plan the other day, and one of my coworkers found that I was using *in to* incorrectly in the sentence

> Data will be imported **in to** the database.

What is the difference between *in to* and *into*?

Comment: You can find the answer to this question at http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, in this particular case, *into* would be the correct choice.  As for pronunciation...in my experience (American English), one would say *into* at a faster clip relative to *in to*.  Otherwise, there's no difference.

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb, if you can take the part starting with "to..." and put it at the beginnig of the sentence instead, then write it separately. In other cases, writers would tend to write "into":

> Step **into** the function. (Ungrammatical: "*To the function, step in.")
>
> Step **in to** find the bug. (Grammatical "To find the bug, step in.")